# How to embed basic weather report for current time for fixed location in web page?

Tags: web, embed, weather

## What I need:

I need to output a basic weather reports based on the current time and a fixed location (a county in the Republic of Ireland).

## Output requirements:

1. Ideally plain text accompanied with a single graphical icon (e.g.
   sun behind a cloud etc.).
2. Option to style output.
3. No adverts; no logos.
4. Free of charge.
5. Numeric Celsius temperature and short textual description.

I appreciate I'm that my expectations are high so interpret the list more as a "wish-list" rather than delusional demands.

## What I've tried:

http://www.weather-forecast.com - The parameters for the iframe aren't configurable enough. Output is too bloated.

Google Weather API - I've played with PHP solutions to no avail though in any case, apparently the API is dead: http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/

## My question:

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to embed a simple daily weather report based on a fixed location with minimal bloat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/

It's pretty configurable, although I'm not sure if there is still too much info for your needs. I've only tried it with US locations; all you need is a zipcode. The examples show using locations from other countries. I'm assuming it's a similar setup to get locations added for Ireland.

Comment: I've successfully applied your solution and I'm happy to say it indeed fulfills all of my listed requirements. Very grateful. Thanks. The Irish Republic doesn't use zipcodes though fortunately, cities and place names can additionally be used to find the location ID. Thanks again for a lightweight, configurable and free solution.